# elasticsearch aggregations on a filtered result set

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to utilize the aggregations feature in elasticsearch.

1. Is there a way to filter a set of documents and then apply the aggregation on the
   filtered set of documents?
2. Is there a way to retrieve a paginated set of buckets from the aggregator? I am looking at potentially a million buckets and would like to get the buckets in a paged fashion.

I searched for information about this and came across this very useful article on aggregations.
https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-aggregations/
But I am not able to find any information about filtering and pagination in combination with aggregation

Answer (score 3):

From the [ElasticSearch guide on aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) (emphasis mine):

> An aggregation can be seen as a unit-of-work that builds analytic information over a set of documents. The context of the execution defines what this document set is (e.g. **a top-level aggregation executes within the context of the executed query/filters of the search request**).

So yes, you can filter a set of documents and only then apply the aggregation, by using a query followed by an aggregations clause.

```
{
  "query": { /* any query */ },
  "aggs" : { /* aggregations on resulting documents */ }
}
```

I don't think you can paginate through aggregation results, but perhaps `from` and `size` would work.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to filter based on the bucket values? I want buckets 1 to 10 out of 10000000 buckets where bucket's average is < 5000. When I searched for this, I got a link to https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256 .. How is this the same as field collapsing?

Comment: With facets, you can control the ordering of the resulting terms and the number of terms you want to see. I assume you can do the same with aggregations. It depends on the specific aggregation you want to use. I suggest you open a new question with an example of the aggregation you're using, where people could answer with more context.